# Storing class in List using while loop

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I'm reading data into a personnel class and then storing the personnel class into a collection.

```
ObservableCollection<Personnel> Personnels = new ObservableCollection<Personnel>();
Personnel personnel = new Personnel();
```

...code omitted...

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
   personnel.PersonID = myReader.GetInt32(0);
   personnel.PersonNameID = myReader.GetInt32(1);
   personnel.PersonWage = myReader.GetInt32(2);
   personnel.PersonWages = String.Format("{0:N0}", personnel.PersonWage);
   // more personnel. items...
   Personnels.Add(personnel);       }
```

My problem is that the Personnels collection is filled entirely with personnel records of only the last personnel record read in. Say 100 personnel class records in the Personnels collection but all with the same data, that of the last personnel class read.

Why is the Personnels collection not being filled with each different personnel class as it is read in the loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are referencing to same object.  Change your code as:

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
   personnel = new Personnel();
   personnel.PersonID = myReader.GetInt32(0);
   ...
}
```

***Additional information:***

When an object of the class is created, the variable to which the object is assigned holds only a reference to that memory. Changes made through one variable are reflected in the other variables because they both refer to the same data.

Comment: Ah, knew it was something obvious. Thanks.